# Custom version number for Jenkins Build

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins job to build various .Net applications. The job requires user to select an application and it builds release artifacts for the selected application.

I would like to increment build number per application.

Example:

```
Jenkins Build #1 - "App A" - Build1.1
Jenkins Build #2 - "App B" - Build1.1
Jenkins Build #3 - "App A" - Build1.2
Jenkins Build #4 - "App A" - Build1.3
Jenkins Build #5 - "App B" - Build1.2
```

I have been using $BUILD_NUMBER however $BUILD_NUMBER is incremented for each build. What is the best way to assign incremental build number for each application?

Comment: Use separate jobs for separate apps, use custom label option.

Comment: Your build 1 and build 2 produces same build version 1.1. Best way is to separate the jobs. it would be easy and simple. Implementing a login would make it complicated. Keep it simple. I may be wrong. What is the use for it ?

Comment: I understand using separate job will solve the issue. However, I do not want to duplicate Jenkins configuration for each job so I am trying to use one job to build them.